# PhpStorm: SCSS File Watcher - how to disable source maps?

Tags: sass, phpstorm

I use SCSS file watcher in PhpStorm 9 and would like to **disable** source maps generation (.map files). How to configure a watcher for this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

if you've followed jetbrain's [tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/transpiling-sass-less-and-scss-to-css.html) on how to work with sass/scss,
you probably installed ruby-sass (there's also node-sass).
any way phpstorm lets you define arguments when you setup a new watcher (settings->tools->file-watchers).

add the `--no-source-map` flag and it'll prevent sourcemap generation.

[image]

Comment: The argument is now `--no-source-map`

Answer (score 0):

the answer of @nitsan-baleli is correct **--no-source-map** (default is --source-map) , but the image is not correct!

> phpstorm path: File > Settings... > Tools > File Watchers

[image]